# Can offline web apps be a replacement for desktop apps?

Tags: offline, tablet-pc

I work on a desktop sales app that is run off a tablet and was wondering if this and other "traditional" desktop tablet applications could be viable as a offline web application.  The main difference with tablet applications being the inking support. I think a web app can get close with browser gestures.

Comment: You might get a better response if you remove the mention of tablets - I'm not sure it's relevant to your main question.

Comment: I was more talking about the inking integration in apps. Guess I can edit that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the distinction between a tablet and a laptop. The decision to build an off line web application should be no different regardless of the medium.

Comment: I think he/she is just asking whether offline web apps are a viable alternative to winforms app, not anything about tablets vs. laptops.

Answer (score 1):

The main different is the inking (gesture) support.